# Database persistence in ECS Fargate

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, amazon-efs

We are running a MongoDB container in ECS Fargate. The ECS services starts up fine and database is accessible.

But how do I make it persistent as we all know that container storage is ephemeral? I have tried to mount efs file system following AWS documentation. The service gets created and the task runs fine but I am unable to access the database anymore. As in, I am unable to even login.

As far as EFS goes, I have tried both versions - unencrypted as well as encrypted.

My Task definition for MongoDB is as follows: (have removed the part where username and password parameters are passed)

```
{
    "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-2:1234567890:task-definition/mongo_efs_test_1215:2",
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "name": "mongo_efs_container_1215",
            "image": "public.ecr.aws/docker/library/mongo:latest",
            "cpu": 0,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "containerPort": 27017,
                    "hostPort": 27017,
                    "protocol": "tcp"
                }
            ],
            "essential": true,
            "entryPoint": [],
            "command": [],
            "environment": [],
            "mountPoints": [
                {
                    "sourceVolume": "efs-disk",
                    "containerPath": "/data/db"
                }
            ],
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-group": "/ecs/mongo_efs_test_1215",
                    "awslogs-region": "us-east-2",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "family": "mongo_efs_test_1215",
    "taskRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
    "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
    "networkMode": "awsvpc",
    "revision": 2,
    "volumes": [
        {
            "name": "efs-disk",
            "efsVolumeConfiguration": {
                "fileSystemId": "fs-dvveweo837af981fa",
                "rootDirectory": "/",
                "transitEncryption": "DISABLED",
                "authorizationConfig": {
                    "iam": "DISABLED"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "requiresAttributes": [
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.awslogs"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-awslogs"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.efsAuth"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.19"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.efs"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.task-iam-role"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.25"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.18"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.task-eni"
        }
    ],
    "placementConstraints": [],
    "compatibilities": [
        "EC2",
        "FARGATE"
    ],
    "requiresCompatibilities": [
        "FARGATE"
    ],
    "cpu": "256",
    "memory": "512",
    "runtimePlatform": {
        "operatingSystemFamily": "LINUX"
    },
    "registeredAt": "2022-12-15T12:06:34.477Z",
    "registeredBy": "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:root",
    "tags": []
}
```

Can someone please guide me? I am struggling with this for a really long time. Any help is really appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: EFS is the correct solution. If it's breaking your container you need to look at the container logs, and possibly use ECS exec to debug the issue. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-exec.html